# New to python classes and objects

Tags: python, class, object, math

Hello Ive only been coding for about 3 weeks now and I stumbled across this code that doesn't do anything when I put it in.

```
class calculation(object):

def multiply(self, a=5, b=6):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
```

I know its simple but I am still new to programming, if anybody could give a brief explanation to why this doesn't work I would really appreciate it.  Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? And what do you mean by *doesn't do anything*? That's not even valid Python code due to messed up indentation.

Comment: class calculation(object):

 def multiply(self, a=5, b=6):
  self.a = a
  self.b = b

Comment: @KhalilG. You can edit your post by pressing the edit button. Please fix the indentation if that was what you were intending to do with your comment.

Comment: That's how It was meant to look

Comment: What exactly is the question here? If you put this in, as posted, it definitely does something: it raises an `IndentationError`. And yet you say "that's how it was meant to look".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because of an indentation error. Indentation is how Python knows that a `def` is a method on a class rather than a plain function at the top level, how it knows which lines are part of a loop and where the loop ends, etc. You have to get it right. But you've got this:

```
class calculation(object):

def multiply(self, a=5, b=6):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
```

Because the `def` is dedented back to the same level as the `class`, there's nothing inside the class. That's not legal; every compound statement (a statement that ends with a `:`, like a class definition) has to be followed by something indented.

On top of that, the fact that `multiply` takes a `self` parameter means it's almost certainly intended to be a method of some class.

So, to fix it:

```
class calculation(object):

    def multiply(self, a=5, b=6):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

---

And now, it works. But it doesn't seem to do anything, does it?

Of course it's always possible that you didn't copy the whole thing. Or that wherever you copied it from, the code was buggy and missing a line. But let's assume this really is a useful function from someone's useful code (except for the indentation error).

First, all you're doing is defining a class. If never create an instance of that class, much less call any methods on it, the class doesn't do anything. But let's assume you knew that, and you know how to create an instance and call methods. It *still* doesn't seem to do anything.

Most likely (again, assuming this is what you're actually asking, and that you copied the code right, and…) what this is doing is storing the operands to use later.

A realistic example of why you'd want to do that would be in some kind of expression-tree library, that calls `multiply` whenever it parses a `*`, and gradually builds up complex expressions out of simple ones, maybe so you can compile the expression to C code or do algebraic transformations on it.

But that probably sounded like gobbledegook to you, so here's a simple but silly example:

```
class calculation(object):

    def multiply(self, a=5, b=6):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

table = []
for a in range(1, 5):
    row = []
    for b in range(1, 5):
        col = calculation()
        col.multiply(a, b)
        row.append(col)
    table.append(row)

print('Times table')
for row in table:
    for col in row:
        print('{} x {} = {}'.format(col.a, col.b, col.a * col.b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the function inside the `class` is misindented. Try indenting that. Also, for your `multiply` function, you probably want to return the two values multiplied:

```
class calculation(object):
    def multiply(self, a=5, b=6):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        return self.a * self.b
```